# 'invalid conversion from int to int*'

Tags: c++, templates, reference

I have a template class `template <typename T> class SomeClass`. It has a member `T* data[10]`, and a method:

```
void add(const T& item){
    data[indexToInsert++] = item;
}
```

In `main()`, there is the following code:

```
SomeClass<int> container;
container.add(10);
```

On the second line, I get this error:

```
invalid conversion from int to int*
```

I don't understand why I get this error. The integer `10` is passed as const reference to `add()`. Then, as a const reference, it's assigned to an array of pointers.

Either some of my assumptions are wrong (for example, is `T* data[10]` actually an array of pointers?), or something that I think should work doesn't.

Please explain the technical reasons to why this fails and how to fix it.

Comment: `T* data[10]` is an array of pointers of type `T`. You probably want an array of `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The member `data` is declared as an array of `T*`, i.e. an array of pointers as you said yourself.

```
T* data[10] // 'data' is an array of T*.
```

To declare an array of `T` use:

```
T data[10]; // 'data' is an array of T.
```

You get the error because you are trying to assign an `int` to an array element of type `int*`. Signed integers are *not* implicitly convertible to addresses/pointers.

Also remember that a reference is basically an alias of an object i.e. it behaves as if you pass the object itself but with reference semantics. You can *not* assign a reference to a pointer, but you *can* assign a reference to an object.

### Example

```
int  i = 5;
int& r = i;  // Reference to 'i';
int* p = &i; // Pointer to 'i'.

std::cout << r << std::endl; // Outputs '5'.
std::cout << p << std::endl; // Outputs the address of 'i'.
```

Comment: So the correct thing to do would be `void add(const T& item){ data[indexToInsert++] = &item; }`? I.e. since `data[indexToInsert++]` is a pointer, I should assign it the address of whatever `item` is referencing?

Comment: @AvivCohn Yes, if your intention is to store the addresses of the objects you pass to `Array::add`. Remember though that if the objects the pointers point to is destroyed you get **dangling pointers** which is UB to access.

Comment: My intention is to store all items in this class by reference. But since C++ doesn't allow an array of references, I settled for an array of pointers. BTW do C++ containers usually store stuff by reference (i.e. via pointers or reference) or by value?

Comment: @AvivCohn Containers in the *standard library* is predominantly templates which means that you can specify the value type at compile time. The specified value type is always stored by value.

Comment: So for example if I store a `Thing` in a vector, the `Thing` is *copied* in the vector? And when I retrieve it, it's copied again?

Comment: @AvivCohn Yes and no, what you pass to `std::vector<Thing>::push_back` is copied or *moved* but if you retrieve something using e.g. `std::vector<Thing>::at` you get a reference to the stored object.

Answer (score 0):

You hit the nail on the head: T* data[10] is an array of pointers.

Change your member array to:

```
T data[10];
```

...and you'll be fine.